# Troubleshoot upgrade of paid app

Tags: updates, samsung, osmand

I'm experiencing a strange problem trying to upgrade a paid app (OsmAnd+, now installed 1.9.5) on my phone (Samsung GT-8752). The download stops reproducibly at 28.75/39 MB, then an installation is attempted which fails with the message "Couldn't install on USB storage or SD card".

Did anyone else experience a similar problem?
Is there a way to troubleshoot download/installation issues like this? Where would I look for log files?

A [related issue](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/42825/installupgradeto-osmand-version-201-fails-on-samsung-notes) appears to have been solved by uninstall/reinstall, but just like the OP there I'd prefer not to uninstall.

Comment: Do you have a computer available with ADB to communicate with the device? I take it you prefer to not uninstall to not lose your settings etc., but there are ways around that I could offer.

Comment: @Izzy: Thanks. I could connect via ADB (never did with this device, though). I don't want to lock myself out of using OsmAnd+ on this particular device, that's why I'm not too keen on uninstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have ADB available to use, here's one proposed way:

1. Make a backup of your current installation (app and data):

   ```
   adb backup -f osmand.ab -apk net.osmand.plus
   ```
2. Same, data only

   ```
   adb backup -f osmand-data.ab -noapk net.osmand.plus
   ```
3. Uninstall the app (`.apk`) while keeping its data:

   ```
   adb uninstall -k net.osmand.plus
   ```
4. Install the new version from play

If the last step succeeds, you're done and the new version should be installed and working. Otherwise, repeat step #3 without the `-k` switch, then step #4 again, and finally restore the data from your second backup:

```
adb restore osmand-data.ab
```

If that should fail as well, just restore the first (full) backup to get back to where you are now. But I'm pretty confident at least the second run will work out fine.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me. However, I don't see my device with `adb devices` (even after `sudo adb start-server`), and I can't seem to enable USB debugging (following [some random instructions](http://tarunmittal5477272.buzznet.com/user/journal/17358610/enable-usb-debugging-samsung-galaxy/) but the "build number" item is greyed out on my device -- WTF...). Any way to do the same from within the phone?

Comment: Afraid not. I don't know about your computer (OS, setup, etc.) – but all flavours have already been asked for using the [adb tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adb) (also check the [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)). Maybe you've not the correct driver installed (Windows), or lack the corresponding UDEV rules (Linux) for your device?

Comment: No, build options were not activated on my phone yet. Didn't follow the "tap seven times" instruction. -- Now I'm connected, but the `osmand.ab` file created by your command line is rather small -- 115k, much less than the size of the app.

Comment: Strange size indeed: 41 byte would be an "un-backupable app" (just the header), but this seems to contain something. What OS you're working with? Maybe you can convert the `.ab` to a `.tar.gz` to check its contents (how to do that was explained in multiple answers; my [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) e.g. contains a simple Shell script to do that). Also: Is your device rooted? Are you by any chance even using the Xposed Framework?

Comment: I've extracted files from both `osmand.ab` and `osmand-data.ab`, the contents of the archives seem to be identical (settings in XML files, ...). It's a paid app -- perhaps even the `-apk` switch backups only the settings, not the app?

Comment: That's why I asked whether your device is rooted. There's an Xposed module that can take care for that; TitaniumBackup would be an alternative tool to use. But both require root. And yes, developers can have their apps "opt-out" from ADB backups. What I didn't know was they seem to be able to also only exclude the `.apk` while allowing the backup/restore of data, which is a good thing; all the times I've seen this, the app was "blocked" completely.

Comment: Sorry, chat doesn't work. No, device is not rooted. Crossing fingers, then... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Chat works for me. I rawly remember having had issues with that years ago, which is due to different servers being involved (from SE/SO side). I can't remember however the details to fix it; something with JavaScript (guess you've got NoScript or the like running?), cookies, and LocalStorage... Ah, here it is: [Cannot log into chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76092/192154) – see [my answer on that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141926/192154). // Anyway: you should be able to "fresh install" the app. Only risk is losing its data then. Minimal risk I'd say.